# Rails I18n - How can I change other locale with the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, header, internationalization

I set a button to change the locale in layout header.

```
<% if I18n.locale.to_s == "ja" %>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to "Việt / 日本語", {:locale => "vi"}, {class: "nav-link"} %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to "Việt / 日本語", {:locale => "ja"}, {class: "nav-link"} %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

After making sign-up failed deliberately, in the same page, this button links to index action based on RESTful.
But what I want is the link to the same page but with the another locale.
Is there any way to resolve this without override the path to index action ?